# How to set Excel cell format as text using node js

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement to generate a report in excel file using node js. I just used "excel4node" package to generate the report successfully, but the cell format is in general category(reference image https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/49247/348091/99yTCY4dzUwywIJ/Cell_format_category_General.png), is there any option to generate it in text category.

## Sample Code snippet

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/49247/348091/N6O02XIeabLDCff/server.js

Comment: Relevant code should be included as text in question body, not as links or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the style object, the resulting cells will be in 'Text' format:

```
var xl = require('excel4node');

var wb = new xl.Workbook();
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

// Create custom text style.
var textStyle = wb.createStyle({
    numberFormat: '@'
});

// Set cell to text style
ws.cell(2,1).string('Hello there, I\'m in text format!!').style(textStyle); 
wb.write('test.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. But while am checking the format in the report it doesn't point to text. Please refer the attached screen shot and advice. 
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/49247/348091/6Wq7sVACpnimKih/report.png

Comment: Hi @SatheeshS, thanks for the update. What version of Excel and Which OS are you using? This might be the difference! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Terry, please find the version details,                                             
OS version     :  Windows 10 Enterprise
Excel version :  MS Excel 2016 Desktop App

Comment: Hi @SatheeshS, could you try downloading this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4x37c5itd36d4z/test.xlsx?dl=0 and see if you get the same result when you open it? Thanks!

Comment: Cool, thanks for that, I can't reproduce the same result, I've tried a few different versions of Excel and it's showing as text format. Strangely this include MS Excel 2016!

Comment: Hi, Can you try selecting the A2 Cell in Excel and then right-click and select Format Cells? Just so we're doing exactly the same thing! :)

Comment: I think maybe no cell is selected in the original example!

Comment: Hi Terry,  sorry for the delay in my reply. Yes while am selecting the cells it shows as text.  Thank you so much :)